# IOS simulator install sub version

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, version

I've got a running application which seems to crash only in IOS version 9.0.2. With version 9.0 it is working.
I want to debug it with the XCode simulator, but it is only running version 9.0.
How can I get the simulator running IOS 9.0.2?

Comment: I believe your best bet is to install current Xcode 7.1 beta 3 running iOS 9.1, in any case you should be testing this in a real device with 9.0.2 to recreate exact conditions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. You need a real device with the specific version. The simulator doesn't support minor point releases.